# How do I solve for $v_2$ where $mv_1^2 + MU_1^2 = mv_2^2 + M U_2^2$ and $MU_1 - Mv_1 = MU_2 - mv_2$ by eliminating $U_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I was trying to solve the head on collision slingshot problem where the rocket moving with speed $v_1$ approaches a planet which is moving with speed $U_1$. I wanted the final speed of the rocket ($v_2$). $U_2$ is the final speed of the planet. Mass of planet is $M$. Mass of rocket is $m$. So I made two equations-

$$ M(U_1)^2 + m(v_1)^2 = M(U_2)^2 + m(v_2)^2 $$
$$ M(U_1) - m(v_1)  = M(U_2) - m(v_2) $$

However, I am unable to eliminate $U_2$ to get ($v_2 = 2U_1 + v_1$) as the answer by also taking $\frac{m}{M} = 0$

**Note** :- This is a head on u-turn slingshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting $ U2=-U1-v1-v2 $ (Remember, these are added according to vector rules)

writing the two equations as,
\begin{equation}
M(U1)^{2}-M(U2)^{2}=m(v2^{2})-m(v1^{2})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies M(U1-U2)(U1+U2)=m(v2-v1)(v2+v1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
M(U1-U2)=m(v1-v2)
\end{equation}
Divide last two equations to get the relation.

Comment: Oh damn thanks! I got it. I had forgotten :/